# How to search more than one things simultaneously in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, search

I wann make app wich search more than once thing from my firebase real-time database for recycler view.

My database looks like

```
Node
.
.Item
  .
  ...pushKey()
       .
       . Name:- "iodex"
       . Type:- "balm"
```

Now,i know how to search only one thing let say Name.  By

```
database.getRefrence().child("Item"). orderByChild ("Name"). startAt(...).endAt(...);
```

But i want to search both Name and Type simultaneously, So how can i do?
Thank you

Comment: That's not possible with Realtime Database without making multiple queries.  You might want to consider switching to Firestore if you want [compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) using logical AND among multiple fields in documents.

Comment: @DougStevenson so in firestore database ,is it possible? Beacuse i am not familiar with firestore

Comment: As Doug suggested, if you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), then I think that [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444) might help.

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property, like `"Type_Name": "balm_iodex"` and then search on that. For a longer example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase